# Slider disappears if the height is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, web, slider

I am making a slider using html and css. It's working fine, but if I set the height to 100%, it disappears. It works fine if I use pixels instead of percentage, but when I use suppose 100% or anything with percentage it will not show up.

It is all happening in the .imgcont

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.slides {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.imgcont {
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  animation: showpromo 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes showpromo {
  0%{background-image: url(1.JPG); background-size: 100% 100%;}
  15%{background-image: url(2.JPG); background-size: 100% 100%;}
  20%{background-image: url(3.JPG); background-size: 100% 100%;}
  35%{background-image: url(4.JPG);background-size: 100% 100%;}
  40%{background-image: url(5.JPG); background-size: 100% 100%;}
  55%{background-image: url(1.JPG); background-size: 100% 100%;}
  60%{background-image: url(2.JPG);background-size: 100% 100%;}
  75%{background-image: url(3.JPG);background-size: 100% 100%;}
  80%{background-image: url(4.JPG);background-size: 100% 100%;}
  100%{background-image: url(5.JPG);background-size: 100% 100%;}    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "slides">
        <div class="imgcont">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will work for you.**

Instead of `100%` **width** to the `.slides` I have used `100vw` and for **height** `100vw`

**you can find `vw` documentation [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).**

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.slides {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 5px;
}

.imgcont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: showpromo 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes showpromo {
  0% {
    background-image: url(http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  15% {
    background-image: url(https://hdwallpaperz.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Images-9.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  20% {
    background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  35% {
    background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url(http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/58dbde7c77bb7050008b4ae9-1190-625/nasas-1-billion-jupiter-probe-just-sent-back-breathtaking-new-images-of-the-gas-giant.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  55% {
    background-image: url(http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  60% {
    background-image: url(https://hdwallpaperz.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Images-9.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  80% {
    background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url(http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/58dbde7c77bb7050008b4ae9-1190-625/nasas-1-billion-jupiter-probe-just-sent-back-breathtaking-new-images-of-the-gas-giant.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="imgcont">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this was helpful for you if there is any doubt please do ask me.

Comment: Will this be responsive after using vw?

Comment: Yes it will be always 100% of screen width `vw` = `Viewport Width`